# How to constrain a callback to be an arrow function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How would one force a callback to be an arrow function?
Or in case it is possible, how would one force 'this' context to be preserved?

Is it possible to do this during compile time with proper typing?

```js
class MyClass {

  callback: ()=>void;

  // This should force the consumer to use either arrow functions or 
  // Ensure that 'this' context is the correct one
  constructor(config: { callback: ()=>void }) {
    this.callback = config.callback;
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.callback(); // this needs to preserve the 'this' context of the consumer
    // Is it possible to bind the function invocation with the correct 'this' somehow?
  }
}



class SecondClass {

  name = 'A Name';

  aFunction() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  anArrowFunction = () => {
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  // This should fail ❌
  myClass1 = new MyClass({ callback: this.aFunction}); 
  // This should succeed ✅
  myClass2 = new MyClass({ callback: this.anArrowFunction}); 
}
```

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73ap05rh/) to demonstrate that an arrow function will provide the expected result whereas a normal function will result missing values (undefined).

Comment: You should be passing everything necessary as parameters to the callback

Comment: I think the responsibility of binding is on the consumer

Comment: I'm not sure you can reliably (there may be hacky ways of doing it with `toString()` but if the function passed was babel built or something that'd probably not work). I don't think you should either -- because a consumer could well have a legitimate `function` that they have correctly bound.

Comment: This isn't quite a [mre]; could you [edit] to include some examples of things which should succeed and things which should fail, hopefully where there are obvious runtime errors on things that should fail?  Since TypeScript doesn't enforce `this`-compatibility everywhere (e.g., there's no `--strictThis` flag as requested in [ms/TS#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968)), my guess is that this will either be impossible or possible but very annoying.  I can't say for certain without some usable examples to test against, though.  Following.

Comment: You might want the example to use `this.name.toUpperCase()` so that you actually get a runtime error if the bad thing happens

Comment: So yeah, it's as bad as I thought, since there's no `--strictThis`.  See [this playground link[(https://tsplay.dev/NavV9m); you can say that `callback` must not require a special `this` context, but TS doesn't mark methods as requiring a special `this` context automatically (`--strictThis` would do that).  You can mark methods yourself this way, but anyone who thinks to do that would already avoid passing methods as callbacks.  Right now this is beyond TypeScript's abilities. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes it addresses my question

Comment: Hmm, it's been quite a while since you posted this question and I asked for clarification.  I could possibly look at this again, but only if I have some expectation that you'd engage in a timely manner.  Is that possible?